# Comparing and converting multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, d3.js, ramda.js

In an app i'm logging click events per day per user and i'd like to visualize them with d3. 
The line chart shows a line for every user. y-axis is the sum of clicks and x-axis is the day.
On some days users do not use the app so there's no data for that day.
But d3 demands that all arrays are of the same length and contain the same data structure. how can i fill the gaps efficiently?

Example data:

```
user01: [[01.Jun, 54],[02.Jun, 32], [05.Jun, 14], [07.Jun, 87]]
user02: [[01.Jun, 89],[02.Jun,  4], [03.Jun, 93], [05.Jun, 23], [06.Jun, 57]]
user03: [[03.Jun, 57],[06.Jun, 11], [07.Jun, 45]]
```

Should be converted to:

```
user01: [[01.Jun, 54],[02.Jun, 32], [03.Jun,  0], [05.Jun, 14], [06.Jun,  0], [07.Jun, 87]]
user02: [[01.Jun, 89],[02.Jun,  4], [03.Jun, 93], [05.Jun, 23], [06.Jun, 57], [07.Jun,  0]]
user03: [[01.Jun,  0],[02.Jun,  0], [03.Jun, 57], [05.Jun,  0], [06.Jun, 11], [07.Jun, 45]]
```

Sometimes there is no click event on a certain day, in this example on the 04.Jun no user was online so that data is not needed.

My idea would be to...

1.) generate an array of all occuring unique x-values [01.Jun, 02.Jun, 03.Jun, 05.Jun, 06.Jun, 07.Jun]

2.) check for every users' array if there is an entry for that day

3.) if not than create an entry with 0.

Since the data is live updated and the number of users is variable: Is there an efficient way to do that, preferably with ramda?

Thanks for your help!

Muff

**EDIT:** The Days are Date Objects

Comment: Have a look at the chapter [*Padding for zero values*](https://leanpub.com/D3-Tips-and-Tricks/read#leanpub-auto-padding-for-zero-values) from the book [*D3 Tips and Tricks*](https://leanpub.com/D3-Tips-and-Tricks/read). The chapter was inspired by the following question on SO: [*"How to add in zero values into a time series in d3.js / JavaScript"*](/q/23227991).

Comment: This is the solution, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the most efficient solution, but I consider it idiomatic Ramda code:

```
//  data Day = Mon | Tue | Wed | Thu | Fri | Sat | Sun
//
//  Day satisfies Ord, the class of orderable types.
const Mon = 1;
const Tue = 2;
const Wed = 3;
const Thu = 4;
const Fri = 5;
const Sat = 6;
const Sun = 7;

//    days :: Array Day
const days = [Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun];

//    defaultPairs :: Pair Day Integer
const defaultPairs = R.map(day => [day, 0], days);

//    fillGaps :: Array (Pair Day Integer) -> Array (Pair Day Integer)
const fillGaps = pairs => {
  const toInsert = R.differenceWith(R.eqBy(R.head), defaultPairs, pairs);
  return R.sortBy(R.head, R.concat(pairs, toInsert));
};

fillGaps([[Mon, 54], [Tue, 32], [Fri, 14], [Sun, 87]]);
// => [[1, 54], [2, 32], [3, 0], [4, 0], [5, 14], [6, 0], [7, 87]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using loop. It's working fine. I added `Thu` for Thursday, I thought maybe you missed that. But if you don't need that, remove that from `days` array.

```
var user01 = [
  ['Mon', 54],
  ['Tue', 32],
  ['Fri', 14],
  ['Sun', 87]
];

var days = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'];

function fillGap(input) {
  var data = [];
  var index = 0;
  days.forEach(function(day) {
    if (input[index][0] == day) {
      data.push(input[index]);
      index++;
    } else {
      data.push([day, 0]);
    }
  });
  return data;
}

console.log(fillGap(user01));
```

Output:

> > [ ["Mon", 54], ["Tue", 32], ["Wed", 0], ["Thu", 0], ["Fri", 14], ["Sat", 0], ["Sun", 87] ]

I created a jsbin, you can experiment there.

http://jsbin.com/hunudul/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Thanks! I should have been more clear: The Weekday abreviation i just chose for the example, in fact its a Date object and They are not predefined like the Weekdays. I edited the Question.

Comment: @Raggamuffin Don't waste other's time posting wrong question and then keep on updating over the week.

Comment: @Raggamuffin `01.Jun` is neither a string nor a variable name, why do you look at the actual values and then post.

Comment: Time can only be wasted by one's own existence - Thanks for your patience.